# A confusing notation for the inverse of an injection in Folland's book.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

In Folland's Real Analysis (1999), I came across the notation $f^{-1}$ that is used to denote the inverse of an injection $f$. Though he did not explicitly call it an inverse, I am a bit embarrassed by using $f^{-1}$ for injections.

> (p. 7) If $f: X \to Y$ is injective, pick $x_0 \in X$ and define $g: Y \to X$ by $g(y) = f^{-1}(y)$ if $y \in f(X)$, $g(y) = x_0$ otherwise.

In this context, it seems that $f^{-1}$ is used as the left inverse of $f$, while $g$ is precisely the left inverse. But the book does not previously introduce the notion of the left inverse, but only the inverse of a bijection.

Is it allowed to use $f^{-1}$ as the notation for the left inverse?

**Update**:

I found a reasonable rationale for this notation: [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)

Comment: As long as the book defines $f^{-1}$ as the left inverse, you're OK. The author is really describing the preimage of an injective function as a function, rather than explicitly as a set.

Comment: $f^{-1}(y)$ is the set of values that get mapped to $y$. This is well defined even for non-injective functions.

Comment: @JohnDouma But the fiber is a set though it's at most a singleton. I am not asking about whether it's reasonable or not, but just about whether it is usual or not.

Comment: It is a singleton set for injective functions. My point is that the notation $f^{-1}$ does not imply that the function has an inverse.

Comment: @JohnDouma We use $f^{-1}$ for both inverse and preimage. Yes, but that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the function $g:Y\rightarrow X$ is defined as
$g(y) = f^{-1}(y)$ if $y$ is in the range of $f$. In this case we have $f(g(y))=y$ and $g(y)$ is uniquely determined as the preimage of $y$ since $f$ is injective.

If $y$ is not in the range of $f$, then simply set $g(y)=x_0$ such the function is defined for all elements of $Y$.